# How to prevent iOS decolorize image below a popover/alert

Tags: ios, tintcolor

In my iPad app, images on UI elements with a `tintColor` and created with `UIImage`'s `.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)`, decolorize and become grey during the time a popover or alert is on screen.  Because `borderColor`, which I set on some of these elements, is not affected, this looks off.

Why are these colors turned into grey?
How can prevent this from happening?

I've seen this on iOS 10 and 11.

[image: No Popover/Alert]
[image: With Alert]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @nathan Thanks for having a look. Images added.

Comment: Can you change the image to `.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)`? Or changed the border color when `isEnabled == false`?

Comment: @beyowulf Then of course `tintColor` does not work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `tintAdjustmentMode` of your view to `.normal` to turn it off, though IMO, you should override `tintColorDidChange()` and adjust your `borderColor` to `.lightGray`, or some other matching shade of gray, when `tintAdjustmentMode == .dimmed`. You can find out more [here.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622555-tintadjustmentmode)

Comment: That's it, perfect!