# Template UIImage changes color

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I wrote this code to create a button with a UIImage inside him.

```
func createDrawerBarButton(image : String) {

    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: image)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: UIControlState.normal)

    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35)
    button.tintColor = UIColor(red: 208/255, green: 33/255, blue: 33/255, alpha: 1.0)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.drawerClicked(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton

}
```

When I click on the button, it calls an method that show an alert. This is the method:

```
func drawerClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
    let wifiAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Wi-Fi", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
        let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=WIFI")
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wi-Fi)", message: "Please, connect your WI-FI", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(wifiAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

That works fine, but when the dialog appears, my UIImage change the color. The color that is red turns gray. After I close the dialog the UIImage comes back to red color. I want that image to keep with red color even when alert appears, only slightly darker as the rest of the screen. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is when you tap on button, it became highlighted or selected, but you set image only for normal state, so you need to change this

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: image)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: UIControlState.normal)
```

with this

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: image)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: [.normal, .selected, .highlighted ])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my question was already solved in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46817243/how-to-prevent-ios-decolorize-image-below-a-popover-alert